# Google Spreadsheet Concatenate texte values based on rows

Tags: google-sheets, string-concatenation, data-transform

I have survey answers on Google Spreadsheet with data structured as in the screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIyn.png)

1st line = question (I have 100 question)
2nd line = possible answers, (each question have a different nb of possible answers, from 1 to 15). 1 column = 1 possible answer
3rd line and next = 1 line pr survey respondent

I want to automate concatenate answers per question, in order to have the format below (1 line per question)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7c8o.png)

I tried to concatenate by hand with a formula on each question, adapted by the nb of answers, but this is not sustainable by hand with 100 questions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6rfU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula give the correct output when copied down the column?

`=SPLIT(JOIN("|",BRUT!B2:2),"|")`

I made this demo sheet to show it working:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QACvEUHNSB8dBKWfBkDfaiAxd686QIbxqJqjkONBvCo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Chris, 

Thanks for your answer. Smart trick, I did not think about it ! Unfortunately It doesn't cover 100% my case, as some questions have no answers and results shift (I made an example in your file for resp2)
I think the solution has to dynamicall calculate the nb of possible answers per question (3, 4, 5...) and concatenate those (3, 4, 5...) cells based on each question
Thanks for your time, I'll continue to investigate further

Comment: I've updated the sheet with a longer formula, in which you'll need to add in the possible range of columns for each of your answers: =HSTACK(BRUT!B3,JOIN(,BRUT!C3:E3),JOIN(,BRUT!F3:I3),JOIN(,BRUT!J3:M3))

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, it works well like this !